# Замена значений в столбце df по логическому условию в Pandas. (Категоризация числовых данных)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть столбец со значениями в df:

```html
df.cumsum
0       17.61
1       23.01
2       26.53
3       29.82
4       32.64
5       34.52
6       36.16
7       37.80
8       38.97
9       40.14
10      41.31
11      42.25
12      43.19
13      44.13
14      45.07
15      46.01
16      46.95
17      47.65
18      48.35
19      49.05
20      49.75
21      50.45
22      51.15
23      51.85
24      52.55
25      53.25
26      53.95
27      54.42
28      54.89
29      55.36
        ...  
4401    99.37
4402    99.37
4403    99.37
```

Как на основе значений в этом столбце, создать новый столбец с буквами 'A', 'B','C' при условии:
если значения <= 50 то 'A', от 50 до 80 - 'B' все остальное - 'C'
Пытался так

```
out_eihri.ABC.loc[out_eihri.ABC <= 50] = 'A'
out_eihri.ABC.loc[(out_eihri.ABC > 50) & (out_eihri.ABC < 80)] = 'B'
```

и так

```
out_eihri['ABC'] = out_eihri.Vklad.mask(out_eihri.Vklad <= 50, 'A')
out_eihri['ABC'] = out_eihri.Vklad.mask((out_eihri.Vklad > 50) & (out_eihri.Vklad < 80), 'B')
```

не работает как надо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [pd.cut()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html).

Исходный DF:

```
In [85]: df
Out[85]:
   col
0   10
1   20
2   50
3   51
4   60
5   80
6   81
7  100
```

Решение:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

bins = [-np.inf, 50, 80, np.inf]
labels = ['A','B','C']
df['new'] = pd.cut(df['col'], bins=bins, labels=labels)
```

Результат:

```
In [87]: df
Out[87]:
   col new
0   10   A
1   20   A
2   50   A
3   51   B
4   60   B
5   80   B
6   81   C
7  100   C
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Все получилось!
Но,скажите, пожалуйста,  что значит -np.inf и np.inf, это какие-то константы с плавающей точкой?

Comment: @VladGolovin, `-np.inf` - минус бесконечность, `np.inf` - плюс бесконечность :)

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: @VladGolovin, всегда рад помочь!